# Getting the first elements of a dictionary without using a loop

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

I have this piece of code and was wondering if there was any inbuilt way to do it faster?

Words has a simple tokenized string input.

```
freq_unigrams = nltk.FreqDist(words)
unigram_list = []

count = 0
for x in freq_unigrams.keys():
    unigram_list.append(x)
    count+=1
    if count >= 1000:
        break
```

Comment: Check your indentation -- it doesn't look like it made it through the copy-paste correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does `freq_unigrams.keys()` return a list? If so, how about the following:

```
unigram_list = freq_unigrams.keys()[:1000]
```

This gives you a list containing the first 1000 elements of `freq_unigrams.keys()`, with no looping.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
unigram_list = freq_unigrams.keys()
unigram_list[:] = unigram_list[:1000]
```

This would not make the copy that: `unigram_list = freq_unigrams.keys()[:1000]` does.

Although this might be better with iterators:

```
from itertools import islice
unigram_list[:] = islice(freq_unigrams.iterkeys(),1000)
```

Comment: whether or not `unigram_list[:1000]` makes a copy doesn't depend on what is on the left side of `=`. If unigram_list is a list then slicing creates a (shallow) copy, if it is a numpy array it can create a view (no data copy). You need `unigram_list[:] = ` only if you want to modify the list in place otherwise mere `unigram_list =` might be more efficient (it just binds the name to refer to the copy (a new list created by slicing the old one).

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to get the top 1000 most frequent words in the `words` list you could try:

```
import collections

# get top words and their frequencies
most_common = collections.Counter(words).most_common(1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is theoretically more efficient:

```
import itertools
unigram_list = list(itertools.islice(freq_unigrams.iterkeys(), 1000))
```

...than working off `freq_unigrams.keys()`, because you're only interested in the **top 1000**, and not the remaining *x*, which the using `freq_unigrams.keys()` will also need to populate in the intermediate `list`.

Answer (score 0):

**a little late...

To take the first 1000 keys in your dictionary and assign them to a new list:

```
unigram_list = freq_unigrams.keys()[:1000]
```